# Rxjs - show/hide element with delay and timer

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am trying to implement show/hide functionality using Rxjs in Angular.

I have multiple elements on which I can hover (arrows). After hovering over an `arrow` I am displaying `div`.

I need hover with some delay but this can be done with `debounceTime` and this is not a problem

The problem I have is a global timer which I need.

1. When the user hovers over the `arrow` I should show `div` element after 500ms for example
2. When the user moves the mouse outside the `arrow`, the timer should start and count 5s and after 5s I should hide the `div` element
3. If the user moves the mouse on `div` which was shown during that 5s, the timer should stop and reset
4. When the user moves the mouse outside `div` timer should start again.

I tried:

```
countdownSeconds = 5;
interval$ = interval(1000).pipe(mapTo(-1));
arrowHover$: Observable<any>;
arrowUnhover$: Observable<any>;

onMouseEnter() {
  this.arrowHover$ = from(EMPTY).pipe(mapTo(false));
}

onMouseLeave() {
  this.arrowUnhover$ = from(EMPTY).pipe(mapTo(true));
  this.setTimer();
}

setTimer() {
  this.timer$ = merge(this.arrowHover$, this.arrowUnhover$)
    .pipe(
      startWith(this.interval$),
      switchMap(val => (val ? this.interval$ : empty())),
      scan((acc, curr) => (curr ? curr + acc : acc), this.countdownSeconds),
      takeWhile(v => v >= 0)
    )
    .subscribe(val => console.log(val));
}
```

And when I move the mouse outside `arrow` timer is starting but how to stop it and reset its value? I have no idea what to do next or how to change it to work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly this is what you are looking for:

```
countDownMs = 5000; // in milliseconds
arrowHover$ = new Subject();
isDivShowing = false;
isOnDiv = false;

ngOnInit(){
  arrowHover$.pipe(
    debounceTime(this.countDownMs),
    filter(() => !this.isDivShowing || !this.isOnDiv),
  ).subscribe((hover) => {
    console.log(`${hover ? 'show div' : 'hide div'}`);
    this.isDivShowing = hover;
  });
}

onEnterDiv(){
  this.isOnDiv = true;
};

onLeaveDiv(){
  this.isOnDiv = false;
  this.arrowHover$.next(false);
};


onMouseEnter(){
  this.arrowHover$.next(true);
};

onMouseLeft(){
  this.arrowHover$.next(false);
};
```

Example on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-tjr3vw)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever there are things set in motion but possibly reset or overridden by future events, switchMap and takeUntil are operators to keep in mind.

Below is untested because I am responding via mobile phone, but here's the general idea:

```
const myDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv');

const enter$ = fromEvent(myDiv, 'onMouseEnter').pipe(
  mapTo(true)
);
const exit$ = fromEvent(myDiv, 'onMouseExit').pipe(
  mapTo(false)
);
const destroy$ = NEVER; // Replace this with something that emits once when it should all be recycled, then completes. ...or get rid of this.

let isDisplayed = false;

merge(enter$, exit$).pipe(
  switchMap(isEntering => isEntering === isDisplayed ? EMPTY // Don't emit anything, but cancel whatever might have been brewing from the previous switch map evaluation
    : of(isEntering).pipe(
      delay(isEntering ? 500 : 5000)
    )
  ),
  takeUntil(destroy$)
).subscribe({
  next: isEntering => {
    isDisplayed = isEntering;
    myDiv.style.display = isEntering ? 'block' : 'none';
  }
});
```